# Momentarily ignore values from Observable when another Observable provides a value

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I need to ignore Observable values **for a period of time**  when another Observable provides a value.

Currently, my implementation uses a variable to control blocking (or ignoring).

```
bool block = false;

var blocker = observable1.Do(_ => block = true )
                         .Throttle( _ => Observable.Timer(_timeToBlock)
                         .Subscribe( _ => block = false ));

var receiver = observable2.Where( i => !block && SomeCondition(i) )
                          .Subscribe( i=> EvenMoreStuff(i) );
```

Is there a more Rx way to do this, by combining these two observables?

EDIT: small change to blocker subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first task is to express your `block` variables as an observable.

```
IObservable<bool> blockObservable = observable1
    .Select(x => Observable.Concat(
        Observable.Return(true),
        Observable.Return(false).Delay(_timeToBlock)))
    .Switch()
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Each time `observable1` emits a value, we select an observable that emits `true`, waits `_timeToBlock`, then emits `false`. The `Switch` just always switches to the most recent of those observables.

Here's a marble diagram.  Let's assume that `_timeToBlock` is 3 characters long.

```
observable1      -----x--xx-x-----x-----
select0               T--F
select1                  T--F
select2                   T--F
select3                     T--F
select4                           T--F
switch           -----T--TT-T--F--T--F--
blockObservable  -----T--------F--T--F--
```

Now we can `Zip` your sequence of values with the `MostRecent` value of the `blockObservable`.

```
var receiverObservable = observable2
    .Zip(blockObservable.MostRecent(false), (value, block) => new { value, block })
    .Where(x => !x.block)
    .Select(x => x.value);
```

Comment: Looks good. Of course the solution is to replace `bool` with `Observable<bool>` ! I need to wrap my head around the syntax and do some tests with it...

Comment: @supertopi Did this "browser code" work without any adjustment?

Comment: At least my unit tests passed. Are there any hidden side-effects I should know of? :)

Comment: @supertopi No it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative using disposables you could create a small extension method:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Suppress<TResult, TOther>(
                                    this IObservable<TResult> source, 
                                         IObservable<TOther> other,
                                         TimeSpan delayFor)
{
  return Observable.Create<TResult>(observer => {
    var published = source.Publish();
    var connected = new SerialDisposable();
    Func<IDisposable> connect = () => published.Subscribe(observer);
    var suppressor = other.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(delayFor)
                                .Select(_2 => connect())
                                .StartWith(Disposable.Empty))
    .Switch();

    return new CompositeDisposable(
                connected,
                suppressor.StartWith(connect())
                          .Subscribe(d => connected.Disposable = d),
                published.Connect());
  });
}
```

This will convert the source observable into a `ConnectableObservable`, then every time the `other` source emits it will dispose of its subscription, then reconnect when the timer expires.

Comment: Thanks. It might be best practice to write your own extension methods, but I find this harder to read than Timothy's solution.