# Reactive Extensions: Buffer until other stream completes

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I make a request and wait for response for that request on a Response stream. While waiting there may be updates on the Updates stream.

I would like to have these updates when the reponse stream completes. Like this:

```
Response (cold)   |      x y z |
Updates (hot)     | 1 2    3        4 |

Result            |      x y z 123  4 |
```

I can't seem to get it right. Is there some clever mix of operators that can give me what I need?

Comment: Just thinking out loud. It does look a little like this actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362031/with-reactive-extensions-rx-is-it-possible-to-add-a-pause-command, but with a check for stream complete rather than a boolean. And once unpaused it can never be paused again. So something like hot.StartWithAndBufferUntilComplete(cold).

Comment: Could there be multiple `Response`s?

Comment: @Shlomo There could be multiple events (like x y z above) on the Reponse stream, but once it completes there will be no more Responses, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question's diagram:

Buffer all of the updates until the response completes, then show the rest of the updates as it appears. 
Responses appear immediately.

```
updates.TakeUntil(response.LastAsync())
       .ToArray()
       .SelectMany(x => x)
       .Concat(updates)
       .Merge(response);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply! This seems to work exactly as I need it to, and after a little contemplation I understand it too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will work, though the fact that you can't do it as a one-liner bothers me:

```
var updatesReplayed = updates.Replay();
updatesReplayed.Connect();

var results = response.Concat(updatesReplayed);
```

Here's tests demonstrating the functionality:

```
// time               | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
// Response(cold)     |     x y z |
// Updates(hot)       | 1 2   3       4 |
// Result             |     x y z 123 4 |

var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var updates = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(100.ToMsTicks(), "1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(200.ToMsTicks(), "2"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(400.ToMsTicks(), "3"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(800.ToMsTicks(), "4"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(900.ToMsTicks())
    );

    var response = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(300.ToMsTicks(), "x"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(400.ToMsTicks(), "y"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(500.ToMsTicks(), "z"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(600.ToMsTicks())
    );

    var expectedResults = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(300.ToMsTicks(), "x"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(400.ToMsTicks(), "y"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(500.ToMsTicks(), "z"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(600.ToMsTicks(), "1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(600.ToMsTicks(), "2"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(600.ToMsTicks(), "3"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(800.ToMsTicks(), "4"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(900.ToMsTicks())
    );

    var replayed = updates.Replay();
    replayed.Connect();

    var results = response.Concat(replayed);
    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
    results.Subscribe(observer);

    scheduler.Start();
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedResults.Messages, observer.Messages);
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I did try Replay() but only in combination with StartWith, which does not make any sense in retrospect. This makes a lot more sense :)

Comment: One question though... will the replayed stream stop buffering new messages when it is subscribed to? I know this is not a part of the original question but it's quite essential as the query is very long running.

Comment: Yes. The test results demonstrate that, as the "4" is popped out immediately.

Comment: But my initial tests show that a subsequent subscriber to the same observable would get the full sequence (including the 4 which should not be replayed). Doesn't that mean that the full sequence is buffered?

Comment: Also in the debugger, I can see the "4" is in replayed's internal ReplaySubject. It would be preferable to not have any events added to this buffer after the response stream closes. Newer messages should just be forwarded directly to result.

Comment: Can you add to the marble diagram what you want a subsequent subscriber to see?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I wanted the subsequent subscribers to see only the updates after subscription. Asti's answer fits that requirement. But thank you for your help, it made me see the problem clearer!